# Counting people in a team with a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, join, stored-procedures

I am wanting to create a stored procedure that accepts the team name and year and returns the number of players in that particular team for that particular year. I am working with MYSQL and listed below are the tables I am using:

```
Person     (personID, name, phone, email, year)
Player     (personID, dateOfBirth, school)
playerTeam (personID, teamID)
Team       (teamID, teamName, ageGroup)
```

So far I have tried joining the tables and couting the personID only where teamName and Person.year = the input parameters but to no avail. Any ideas?

After submitting this question, using trial and error, I was able to get this to work using the following statements:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE teamSize (IN team VARCHAR (30), IN YEAR INT) 
BEGIN
          SELECT 
                    COUNT(Person.personID) NumOfPlayers 
          FROM
                    Person AS p,
                    Player,
                    playerTeam,
                    Team 
          WHERE Person.personID = Player.personID 
                    AND Player.personID = playerTeam.personID 
                    AND Team.teamID = playerTeam.teamID 
                    AND Team.teamName = team 
                    AND Person.year = YEAR ;
END //

DELIMITER ;

CALL teamSize('Pirates', 1991);
```

Is there anyway to simplify this using joins etc as at the moment its a bit messy.

Comment: I think you don't need to Join it with `Player` since you don't need the `dateOfBirth` and the `School` of the players.

Comment: Use SQL Ansi-92 Format (like my answer below), not SQLAnsi-89.

Comment: yes but I need the year in Person because for example someone that may be a coach may have been a player in a team in the past and to make comparisons I require the joining table which I can only access through Player

Comment: @batsta13: Yes, you do seem to need the `Person.Year` column, but it doesn't follow you need a join to the `Player` table. You could join the `Person` table directly to `PlayerTeam` using the `PersonID` column. The join to `Player` seems perfectly unnecessary in your particular query.

Comment: @Andriy M: I tried taking out the Person.personID --> Player.personID join but it returned 32 which is the total number of records in my database. There is only one player in my database that played in the Pirates in 1991 and with the person to player join included it only returns it that one entry. Any insight into how I can get your way to work. Code would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, so this means a person may be absent from `Player` but present in `playerTeam`? I wouldn't expect such a model. But I've no doubt there were reasons to design things like that.

Comment: In this situation I believe the join to `Player` must stay, because it acts as a(nother) filter. It seems somewhat unusual, though, that a person can be in a team and not be a player at the same time. So may be you would like to revise your data model. That way you wouldn't need a join to `Player` in this query. So there, you've got an option. But, again, I do not insist it's necessarily a good one for you, because the way your data are organised now might be dictated by other requirements. You must see for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want like this:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE GetPlayerCount (
          IN oTeamName VARCHAR (50),
          IN oYear INT
) AS 
BEGIN
          SELECT 
                    COUNT(a.PersonID) NoOfPlayers 
          FROM
                    Person a 
                    INNER JOIN PlayerTeam b 
                              ON a.PersonID = b.PersonID 
                    INNER JOIN Team c 
                              ON b.TeamID = c.TeamID 
          WHERE b.TeamName = oTeamName 
                    AND a.Year = oYear ;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

but i think this is want you want.

Usage:

```
CALL GetPlayerCount('TeamDog', 2012);
```

Comment: but wouldn't I have to connect from person to player than to playerteam than to team. Can I join person straight to team.

Comment: you can still achieved the result without joining person to player.

Comment: I tried the code you supplied but it wouldn't work however I was able to getting it working by myself. I have inserted my code into the question is that anyway to shorten/clean it up using joins.

Comment: i bet you got Syntax error right? It MySQL, you should change the delimiter first. I'll update the answer.